# Netsuite custom formula field using a CASE statement with multiple WHEN conditions returning "invalid expression"

Tags: sql, case, netsuite

I'm quite new to writing NetSuite sql case statements. I have been able to successfully write CASE statements with single WHEN conditions but when I include multiple WHEN conditions NetSuite returns "invalid expression" error. I am wondering if I need to separate the WHEN conditions with something other than a space. I've seen examples of nested statements with multiple WHEN conditions but NetSuite will not allow nesting of statements in formula fields. Here is my statement which is returning an error:

```
CASE WHEN {item.custitem_custid} IN (05,12) 
THEN {amount}*{item.custitem_sharedat50} 
WHEN {item.custitem_custid} IN (37,42,76) 
THEN {amount}*0.02 ELSE {amount}*{item.custitem_sharedat33} 
END
```

Here is my CASE statement with a single WHEN condition which works:

```
CASE WHEN {item.custitem_custid} IN (05,12) 
THEN {amount}*{item.custitem_sharedat50} 
ELSE {amount}*{item.custitem_sharedat33} END
```

Anybody with NetSuite experience have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You have to initiate and terminate each Case statement

```
CASE WHEN {item.custitem_custid} IN (05,12) 
  THEN {amount}*{item.custitem_sharedat50} 
ELSE 
   CASE WHEN {item.custitem_custid} IN (37,42,76) 
      THEN {amount}*0.02 ELSE {amount}*{item.custitem_sharedat33} 
   END
END
```

This is the Case Statement I am using in a saved search that works

```
CASE WHEN {classnohierarchy} = 'Snow' THEN 
   CASE WHEN {custbody_hdr_cs_status} IN ('Follow-up','Follow-up & Term') THEN 0 
   ELSE 
      CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('NV','NY','PA','SD','UT','VA','WY') THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
      END 
   END 
ELSE 0 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also bumped into the same issue. It seems like a bug in the system. You should file a support ticket to NetSuite. Until this is fixed, use DECODE instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code with multiple **when** . It works for me.

```
var formula = "case  when {internalid} IN (10555) then 'a'"
                 + " when {internalid} IN (10556) then 'b'"
                 + " when {internalid} IN (10557) then 'c'"
                 + " else 'd' end";
var filter = new nlobjSearchFilter('formulatext', null, 'contains', 'a').setFormula(formula);
var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filter);
```

Can you tell us the exact error that you got